# How to show three dots of Overflow menu in android 2.x version

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to  implement three dots of Overflow menu. In honey comb the three dots will be available by default. I want to show three dots of Action Bar combat of Overflow menu in android2.x version. If user clicks the menu button it should also show the three dots menu. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private void forceShowActionBarOverflowMenu() {  
    try {  
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);  
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");  
        if (menuKeyField != null) {  
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);  
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);  
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

and finally you add "forceShowActionBarOverflowMenu();" right after setContentView() in onCreate() in your activity.

Comment: in it is not working in 2.x version three dot is not appearing